# AWS API Gateway Resources and API Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have set up an API GW with multiple resources, one requiring an API Key and the other one **not** requiring an API Key as shown below.

The Swagger resource is configured to not need an API Key, while the other resource has been set up to require one.

The API is deployed to a stage using a usage plan which has an API Key attached to it.

[image]

With this setup, however, I see that unless I pass a valid key in the header for the Swagger resource the call fails with 403 forbidden.

Did I miss a step somewhere?

Comment: How are you extracting the Swagger resource? Which of the 3 options in the console?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, the swagger is generated using nest swagger - https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/introduction